# How to write code that expresses level order for non binary tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

Here `t` denotes a tree. A tree can have a list of children. `act` is a behavior, like `print`. My code shows the correct order for all levels below root `t`. How can I modify the code to include `t` itself?

```
def levelorder_visit(t, act):
    """
    Visit every node in Tree t in level order and act on the node
    as you visit it.

    @param Tree t: tree to visit in level order
    @param (Tree)->Any act: function to execute during visit

    >>> t = descendants_from_list(Tree(0), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)
    >>> def act(node): print(node.value)
    >>> levelorder_visit(t, act)
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    """
    if t:
        for x in t.children:
            act(x)
        for i in t.children:
            levelorder_visit(i,act)
    ###prints out "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" for the above docstring example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an levelorder traversal list and then act upon them.

```
def levelorder_visit(t):
    children = []
    if t:
        children.extend(t.children)
        for ch in t.children:
            children.extend(levelorder_visit(ch))
    return children

def act_traversed(root):
  nodes = [root]
  nodes.extend(levelorder_visit(root))
  for n in nodes: 
    act(n)

act_traversed(n)
```

Comment: Sorry, did not think about that. See the corrected code.